# Is there a way to cut the contect of what I am reading with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, database

I am trying to manipulate this gigant file but google colab tells me I have used all of my ram.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from gzip import decompress

r = requests.get('https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml.gz')
soup = BeautifulSoup(decompress(r.content), 'lxml')

result = soup.prettify().splitlines()
print('\n'.join(result[:1000] + result[-1000:]))
```

I am trying to play with the data but I don't know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the data? `BeautifulSoup` is _not_ the right tool to read a 500 megabyte XML file; use `lxml` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not download the 18MB gzip-file and than parse the xml with `iterparse()`:

```
import requests
import gzip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Download the gzip file
url = "https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml.gz"
resp = requests.get(url) # allow_redirects=True

with open('officialCpeDictionary_v23.xml.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)

# Read the gzip file
input = gzip.open('officialCpeDictionary_v23.xml.gz', 'rb')
input.close

# Parse the result
ns_map = []
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(input, events=('start-ns', 'end',)):
    if event == "start-ns":
        ns_map.append(elem)
    
    if event == 'end':
        print(elem.tag, elem.attrib, "TEXT:", elem.text)

print(ns_map)
```

Output:

```
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}product_name {} TEXT: National Vulnerability Database (NVD)
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}product_version {} TEXT: 5.1
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}schema_version {} TEXT: 2.3
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}timestamp {} TEXT: 2023-09-02T03:51:57.789Z
{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}generator {} TEXT: 
...
```

Option2 - If you like to hold the 18MB file as a temporary file only.
Here I used the `XMLPullParser` (Caution, the download takes a minute):

```
import shutil
import tempfile
import urllib.request
import gzip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parser = ET.XMLPullParser(['start-ns','end',])

url = "https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml.gz"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, tmp_file)

with gzip.open(tmp_file.name, 'rb') as f:
    input = f.readlines()
    
for line in input:
    parser.feed(line.decode('utf-8'))
    #print(line.decode('utf-8'))

ns_map = []
for event, elem in parser.read_events():
    if event == 'start-ns':
        ns_map.append(elem)
    
    if event == 'end':
        print(f'{elem.tag} {elem.attrib} Text: {elem.text}')
```

Option 3 - With `zlib` could a stream decompressed:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import zlib

parser = ET.XMLPullParser(['start-ns','end',])
decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(32 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
url = "https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml.gz"

with requests.Session() as s:
    stream = s.get(url, headers=None, stream=True)
    #print(r.status_code, r.headers, r.request.headers )

    for gzchunk in stream:
        xmlchunk = decompressor.decompress(gzchunk)
        #print(xmlchunk)
        parser.feed(xmlchunk)
        
ns_map = []
for event, elem in parser.read_events():
    if event == 'start-ns':
        ns_map.append(elem)
    
    if event == 'end':
        print(f'{elem.tag}\n \t{elem.attrib}\n \t\t{elem.text}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite, because it’s very fast:

```
import urllib.request
import gzip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml.gz"
file = 'official.gz'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
    
data = gzip.open(file,'rb')

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(data, events=('end',)):
    print(elem.tag) # do something with your xml
    elem.clear()
```